# Comparator in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve my homework. This is the code I use. Comparator for sorting a student list in 2 ways.

```
public class Student {
    public static final Comparator<Student> BY_NAME = new ByName();
    public static final Comparator<Student> BY_Gpa = new ByGpa();

    private static class ByName implements Comparator<Student> {
        public int compare(Student v, Student w) {
            return v.getName().compareTo(w.getName());
        }
    }

    private static class ByGpa implements  Comparator<Student> {
        public int compare(Student v, Student w) {
            if (v.getGpa() == w.getGpa()) return 0;
            else if (v.getGpa() < w.getGpa()) return -1;
            else return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand `Collection.sort`. Why does it have to use a complicated form like that? Why not just a static function in the class like C++ for sorting, instead of returning a class that implements Comparator which has a method compare? It's too complex.

Comment: In java8 you can do fancy stuff like: `Comparators.comparing(Student::getName)`. So you might want to upgrade

Comment: I don't see an actual question here, only a complaint that Java isn't like C++

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, the only real question I'm seeing is asking why Collections.sort is complicated.

Comment: `ByGpa` can be simpler in pre Java 8 by using `return Double.compare(v.getGpa(), w.getGpa())`, (or whatever primitive type `getGpa` returns).

Comment: The idea is that you have a pluggable Comparator. You can compare on something entirely different, by pluggingin  a different Comparator class. The same result _could_ be achieved with static functions, but from an object-oriented perspective, this is more elegant.

Comment: ya, Im sorry. Just try to ask how java build their Collection.sort that make it so complicated like that.

Comment: @sockyone not sure why you think it's more complicated than c++.  Collections.sort is a static method on a class that takes a thing to sort, and optionally a way to sort it, just like std::sort from c++.  If anything it's less complicated sinc e in c++ you need to specify the start and end, while in java you just pass in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8's enhancements to the `Comparator` interface make it a lot more elegant:

```
public static final Comparator<Student> BY_NAME = Comparator.comparing(Student::getName);
public static final Comparator<Student> BY_Gpa = Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getGpa);
```